# We have a one year old modulating Goodman furnace that vibrates on high fan

Tags: furnace, vibration

We've had it for about one year. The last part of its heat cycle it goes to high fan. When on high the furnace shakes and vibrates the main trunk of ductworks. This has been going on for a month. The installer came out and adjusted come work at the furnace that was touching and vibrating. The noise stopped, only temporarily. I think it's an unbalanced motor fan. He doesn't think so. I can watch the furnace shake. Does this seem normal? I've never experienced a furnace that does this. It was fine until about 4 weeks ago. Please give me ideas. I'd like to see a new fan in it. But trying to convince the installer may be difficult.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, please revise to ask something clear and objective. The answer to "Is a wobbly fan normal?", which is obviously "no", isn't of much value to you or the community.

Comment: Please provide photos if possible. This could be unrelated to the fan, such as a flimsy base or uneven floor that compounds normal fan vibrations into an oscillation. At an rate, we need more information.

Comment: spin the squirrel cage fast, like price is right's wheel, and let it come to a rest. Put a mark at the bottom of the circle with a sharpie. Repeat 10 times. The position with the most marks is the heavy side. Add weight to the light side, or remove weight from the heavy side until it balances and a repeat spinning yields an apparently random orientation.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed a number of Goodman furnaces recently and found them to be quiet and smooth-running. The objectionable vibration from yours does seem like it would have to be debris entry, or a defect in installation or in the furnace itself. You should have a 5 year manufacturer parts warranty on the furnace, unless it was registered in which case the warranty is 10 years. The warranty would cover defective parts but not defective installation nor debris that might have gotten into the blower.

First, a bit of troubleshooting. Ensure that you're not wearing loose clothing, any long hair is restrained, and the area around the blower compartment is clear of anything that might get sucked into it. Keep children away. Remove the blower compartment door and bypass the blower door safety switch by taping it in.

A furnace blower can run at multiple speeds. Usually the highest speed is used for air conditioning. You mention that you're in heating season now -- we wouldn't want to actually run an air conditioning compressor during cold weather because it could be damaged if not equipped for "low ambient" operation. So if your system is set up for air conditioning, disable the compressor by turning off its disconnect or circuit breaker. Then adjust your thermostat to call for cooling to make the blower run on high speed. (If your system is not set up for air conditioning, simply install a jumper wire between the R and Y terminals on the controller board.)

Hopefully this will reproduce the vibration. Check whether there are gaps below the furnace cabinet where it is not well-supported by the floor, platform, or ductwork it sits atop.

Have a look at the blower housing. Try to determine whether that's the origin of the vibration. It's possible to reach in and hold the housing while the blower runs, but this must be done with extreme caution to keep the fingers out of the blower wheel.

Stop the thermostat call for cooling (or remove your jumper wire), remove the safety switch bypass, and restore the disconnect for the air conditioner. Turn off the furnace disconnect. With the help of a mirror and a flashlight you can inspect the inside of the blower wheel. Inspect from both sides. Manually rotate the blower wheel and look for any debris sitting inside it. It'll be tough to see into the side where the motor is mounted.

It's possible to remove the blower from the furnace cabinet for easier inspection and stand-alone testing. This entails removing a half-dozen screws, unplugging some connectors, and possibly disconnecting tubes for a condensate drain. Ask a new question and include photos of your blower compartment if you'd like help with this.